# Notification setStyle not working in sdk30

Tags: android, notifications, mediasession

[image]

```
MediaSessionCompat mediaSessionCompat = new MediaSessionCompat(ctx, "tag");
```

When I set .style(), notification is not output.
Is there anything in the mediaSessionCompat that you need to do other than setting context and tag?

Comment: What's not working? Does the notification display? Do you use setMetaData on mediasession? Update your question to provide more info.

Comment: Thanks. When i set .style()   notification is not displaying
How can i use setMetaData on mediasession?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the `setStyle` method on a notification, you need to provide the MediaSession with Metadata.

```
private void updateMetadata () {
mediaSession.setMetadata(new MediaMetadataCompat.Builder()
                                     .putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST, song.getArtistTitle())
                                     .putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM_ARTIST, song.getArtistTitle())
                                     .putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM, song.getAlbumTitle())
                                     .putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_TITLE, song.getTitle())
                                     .putLong(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_DURATION, song.getDuration())
                                     .putLong(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_TRACK_NUMBER, getPosition())
                                     .putBitmap(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM_ART, null)
                                     .build());
}
```

Don't forget to call this method, for example when your data changes. I don't know how you handle that so I can't provide a correct place for it. I'd say the same place you update the notification when a song changes and it's only a suggestion.

Comment: Thank you for your Sharing your knowledge.